# Why does this clojure macro need `'~?

Tags: clojure, macros, quote

*(Apologies if this is a duplicate of another question, my search for all those fancy special characters didn't yield anything.)*

I'm reading [Mastering Clojure Macros](https://pragprog.com/book/cjclojure/mastering-clojure-macros) and have trouble understanding the following example:

```
(defmacro inspect-caller-locals []
  (->> (keys &env)
       (map (fn [k] [`'~k k]))
       (into {})))
=> #'user/inspect-caller-locals
(let [foo "bar" baz "quux"]
  (inspect-caller-locals))
=> {foo "bar", baz "quux"}
```

What is the difference between the following and the much simpler `'k`?

```
`'~k
```

As far as I understand, the innermost unquote `~` should simply reverts the effect of the outermost syntax-quote `, but a short experiment reveals that there's more to it:

```
(defmacro inspect-caller-locals-simple []
  (->> (keys &env)
       (map (fn [k] ['k k]))
       (into {})))
=> #'user/inspect-caller-locals-simple
(let [foo "bar" baz "quux"]
  (inspect-caller-locals-simple))
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: k in this context, compiling:(/tmp/form-init4400591386630133028.clj:2:3)
```

Unfortunately, my usual investigation approach doesn't apply here:

```
(macroexpand '(let [foo "bar" baz "quux"]
                 (inspect-caller-locals)))
=> (let* [foo "bar" baz "quux"] (inspect-caller-locals))
(let [foo "bar" baz "quux"]
  (macroexpand '(inspect-caller-locals)))
=> {}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Instead of macroexpand, try just evaluating the part of the macro you care about, by running this in your repl: `(let [k 'foo] [k 'k \`'~k])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's first establish what the `k` inside the macro is:

```
(defmacro inspect-caller-locals []
  (mapv (fn [k]
          (println (class k)))
        (keys &env))
  nil)
(let [x 1]
  (inspect-caller-locals))
;; Prints:
;; clojure.lang.Symbol
```

So you each `k` inside the function is a symbol. If you return a symbol from a macro (ie generate code from it), clojure will lookup the value that it refers to and print it. For instance you could do this:

```
(defmacro inspect-caller-locals []
  (mapv (fn [k]
          [(quote x) k]) ;; not the "hard coded" x
        (keys &env)))
(let [x 1]
  (inspect-caller-locals))
;; Prints:
;; [[1 1]]
```

What you want however is the actual symbol. The problem (as you noted) is that `quote` is a special form that DOES NOT EVALUTE whatever you pass it. Ie, the k will not obtain the function parameter but stay `k` which is not  usually defined:

```
(defmacro inspect-caller-locals []
  (mapv (fn [k]
          [(quote k) k])
        (keys &env)))
(let [x 1]
  (inspect-caller-locals))
;; => Error
(let [k 1]
  (inspect-caller-locals))
;; Prints:
;; [[1 1]]
```

You somehow need to evaluate what you pass into `quote`, this is not however possible since that isn't what `quote` does. Other functions, such as `str` don't have that problem:

```
(defmacro inspect-caller-locals []
  (mapv (fn [k]
          [(str k) k])
        (keys &env)))
(let [x 1]
  (inspect-caller-locals))
;; Prints:
;; [["x" 1]]
```

The trick is to go one level deeper and quote the `quote` itself so you can pass the symbol to it:

```
(defmacro inspect-caller-locals []
  (mapv (fn [k]
          [;; This will evaluate k first but then generate code that 
           ;; wraps that symbol with a quote:
           (list (quote quote) k)
           ;; Or equivalently and maybe easier to understand:
           (list 'quote k)
           k])
        (keys &env)))
(let [x 1]
  (inspect-caller-locals))
;; Prints:
;; [[x x 1]]
```

Or by using the reader that can do this for you:

```
(defmacro inspect-caller-locals []
  (mapv (fn [k]
          [`(quote ~k)
           `'~k
           k])
        (keys &env)))
(let [x 1]
  (inspect-caller-locals))
;; Prints:
;; [[x x 1]]
```

Because after all:

```
(read-string "`'~k")
=> (clojure.core/seq (clojure.core/concat (clojure.core/list (quote quote)) (clojure.core/list k)))
(defmacro inspect-caller-locals []
  (mapv (fn [k]
          [(clojure.core/seq (clojure.core/concat (clojure.core/list (quote quote)) (clojure.core/list k)))
           k])
        (keys &env)))
(let [x 1]
  (inspect-caller-locals))
;; Prints:
;; [[x 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Some alternative, and equivalent, ways of writing

`` `'~k ``

are:

`` `(quote ~k)     ;; expands the ' reader macro to the quote special form ``

`(list 'quote k) ;; avoids syntax quote entirely`

You are pretty much right to think that

> the innermost unquote ~ should simply reverts the effect of the outermost syntax-quote

The only thing missing from your description there is that you can't pull `quote` outside of a syntax-quoted expression, since `quote` is a special form and changes the meaning of what's inside. Otherwise, 

`` '`~k ``

 would be equivalent to `'k` - and as you noticed, it's not!

I'll echo @amalloy's general advice, that trying syntax-quoted stuff in the REPL, *outside* of the context of macros/macroexpansion, is the best way to get your head around these things.

p.s. Also, I'll make a note that I need to fix this confusion by explaining better in a future book edition ;)